# Why RNN is throwing batch input shape error?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

My `x_train` shape is (798,3) and `y_train` input shape is (798, 1). I am creating a RNN like this

```
def create_rnn_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(SimpleRNN(20,return_sequences=False,stateful=stateful,activation='relu',batch_input_shape=(1,3,1)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adam, metrics=[root_mean_squared_error])

    return model
```

But this returns the error

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected simple_rnn_1_input to
>   have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (798, 3)

My batch size =1 and my timestep is 3 and `dat_dim=1` .Then where am I doing it wrong?
Any help is appreciated.

> EDIT

I changed my x_train to shape (798,3,1) and y_train shape to (798,) and ran the model but it threw an error

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_1 to have shape (20,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

But I can run the model with 1 unit. How do I specify the model to run with 20 units instead of one.

My Network Model is like this and my current L=3.
[image: Network]

Comment: What did you provide as an input?

Comment: @CAFEBABE my input is an array with a shape of (798, 3)

Comment: @Ricky Expand the dimension of input data to add the third axis: `X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=-1)`.

Comment: @today I now changed the x_train shape to  (798, 3, 1) and y_test shape to (798,) and created the model by  `model.add(SimpleRNN(20,return_sequences=False,stateful=stateful,activation='relu',batch_input_shape=(1,3,1)))`. But this throws an error of   `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_1 to have shape (20,) but got array with shape (1,)` .  I need 20 units in my RNN not 1.Do you know why is it working for 1 but not 20 .

Comment: @Ricky The problem is the output shape. It is currently `(None, 20)` but you are passing a `(798,)` (i.e. labels of size 1) as the ground-truth labels.

Comment: @today I don't get you by what do you mean by (None, 20)?Could you please explain it .Thanks

Comment: @Ricky The output shape of the model is `(None, 20)`, which means for each input sample an array of shape `(20,)` is returned as the output. Use `model.summary()` to see this. Since an array of shape `(20,)` is returned for each input sample, you also need to provide targets of shape `(20,)` (i.e. the `y` array passed to `fit` method must have a shape of `(798,20)` and not `(789,)`).

Comment: @today but for whole input sample my expected target is just (789,) so what ia m understanding is I have to converge the 20 outputs into 1. Is it?

Comment: @Ricky If that's the case, then as you mentioned you need to modify the model to make its output shape `(None, 1)`. One way of doing it is to add a `Dense` layer with one unit as the last layer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182329/discussion-between-ricky-and-today).